# How to force scrollview to only scroll vertically in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I want my ScrollView to only scroll vertically but it also scrolls horizontally.  I have the leading and trailing constraints set to 0 but somehow it is still adding space to allow it to scroll.

When I click on the embedded view or scroll view, I see the red lines to the left and right but not sure how to prevent them from being added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should first fix your constraints errors. Because these errors could cause undefined behavior of your views' layout. To disable UIScrollView's horizontally scroll, you only need to make UIScrollView's contentSize.width equal to superView.bounds.size.width. It's not hard to resolve, but you can't do it with such a lot of layout errors.

Answer (score 1):

You must set scrollview's `contentView` width is equal to superView(device Width). Than after your scrollView stop scrolling horizontal.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I do have that set. https://imgur.com/a/O1HNRns

Answer (score 1):

### Follow the routine of creating a vertical scroll view.

- First, You need to change Simulated Size to FreeForm.
  [image]
- Second, Put in a ScrollView, set up Constrains.
  [image]
- Third, Put a View on top of it, set up Constrains.
  [image]
- Fourth, set the layout for SuperView.
  [image]
- Fifth, change Priority and Mutipier
  [image][image]

##### And now we can work up here !